# NSImage missing alpha channel

Tags: swift, macos, image

I'm trying to load this file:

[image]

into an `NSImage` object, like this:

```
NSImage(byReferencingFile: "apple.png")
```

I then save the image back to another file (just for testing purposes):

```
try NSBitmapImageRep(data: image.tiffRepresentation!)?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])!.write(to: url)
```

I save the image by creating a new `NSBitmapImageRep` from the image's `tiffRepresentation`, and then save it into a `png` file.

However, when I open the resulting saved `png` file the transparent background got replaced with a gray background.

Why is this? Can anybody else reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set alpha to true in NSBitmapImageRep:

```
let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: your_data)
imageRep?.hasAlpha = true
```